Not able to decrypt the message from client - RSA cryptography - Golang
The requirement is to have client-server communication using RSA. I am not able to decrypt the message. Created private.pem and public.pem files using the generatekeys.go file.
Created 3 files server.go, client.go and generatekeys.go.
server.go -> This file adds 'n' number of clients. The function recvAndEcho loads the private.pem file and decrypts the message using the private.pem file.
client.go -> This file loads the public.pem file and encrypts the message incoming from the server.
server.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type server struct {
    clients []io.Writer
}

func (s *server) addClient(c net.Conn) {
    s.clients = append(s.clients, c)
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Launching server...")
    srv := &server{}

    // listen on all interfaces
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := ln.Accept()

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        srv.addClient(conn)
        go srv.recvAndEcho(conn)
    }
}

func (s *server) recvAndEcho(c io.ReadCloser) {
    defer c.Close()

    for {
        netData, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        decryptedMessage, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, getPrivateKey(), []byte(netData))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error decrypting message:", err)
            return
        }

        temp := strings.TrimSpace(string(decryptedMessage))
        fmt.Println(temp)
        s.broadcastMsg(netData)
    }
}

func (s *server) broadcastMsg(msg string) {
    for _, cl := range s.clients {
        // Send the original msg back to the client
        _, err := cl.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("server replied: %s\n", msg)))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("server: failed to write!")
        }
    }
}

func loadPrivateKey(filename string) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(data)
    if block == nil || block.Type != "RSA PRIVATE KEY" {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to decode PEM block containing private key")
    }

    return x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
}

func getPrivateKey() *rsa.PrivateKey {
    var err error
    privateKey, err := loadPrivateKey("private.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading private key:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    return privateKey
}

client.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // connect to this socket
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())

    }
    go receive(conn)
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for sc.Scan() {
        if sc.Err() != nil {
            fmt.Println("scanner error!")
        }
        txt := sc.Text()
        b := []byte(txt + "\n")
        _, err := conn.Write(b)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to send data to the server!")
            break
        }

    }

    conn.Close()
}

func receive(c net.Conn) {
    rd := bufio.NewReader(c)
    var inbuf [64]byte
    for {
        n, err := rd.Read(inbuf[:])

        encryptedMessage, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, getPublicKey(), []byte(inbuf[:n]))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error encrypting message:", err)
            return
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to receive msg from the server!")
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(encryptedMessage)

    }
    c.Close()
}

func loadPublicKey(filename string) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(data)
    if block == nil || block.Type != "RSA PUBLIC KEY" {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to decode PEM block containing public key")
    }

    pkey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rsaKey, ok := pkey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("got unexpected key type: %T", pkey)
    }
    return rsaKey, nil
}

func getPublicKey() *rsa.PublicKey {
    var err error
    publicKey, err := loadPublicKey("public.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading public key:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    return publicKey
}

generatekeys.go
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error generating private key:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey

    savePEMKey("private.pem", privateKey)
    savePublicPEMKey("public.pem", publicKey)
}

func savePEMKey(filename string, key *rsa.PrivateKey) {
    outFile, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating file:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    var privateKey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    pem.Encode(outFile, privateKey)
}

func savePublicPEMKey(filename string, pubkey *rsa.PublicKey) {
    pubASN1, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pubkey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling public key:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var pemkey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: pubASN1,
    }

    outFile, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating file:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    pem.Encode(outFile, pemkey)
}


What have you done so far? Have you checked encryption and decryption without network I/O? And also checked whether the ciphertext arrives uncorrupted at the decryption function?

Without network I/O result is fine. And ciphertext is corrupted at the decryption function

It looks like the client receives data from the server, encrypts it, prints the encrypted data out, and does nothing else with it. I'm not really a Go expert unfortunately.

To me the process is also not quite clear. Are you reading the output ciphertexts back in via stdin (with respect to bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin).Scan())? Then you probably have to use a suitable binary-to-text encoding (to prevent the ciphertext from being corrupted), i.e. the ciphertext encryptedMessage should be output Base64 encoded, then entered Base64 encoded (via stdin) and finally Base64 decoded in the decryption function just before decryption.

I will try the approach as you mentioned @Topaco
